# Generating Symmetric Positive Definite Matrices using indices

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to run test cases for CG and I need to generate:

- symmetric positive definite matrices
- of size > 10,000
- **FULL DENSE**
- Using only matrix indices and if necessary 1 vector
  (Like $A(i,j) = \dfrac{x(i) - x(j)}{(i+j)}$)
- With condition number less than 1000.

I have tried:

1. Generating random matrices using `A=rand(N,N)` and then `A'A` to make it Sym. PD. [This increases condition number]
2. Using the vector appraoch as shown but I can't seem to get a function of `(x,i,j)` which will ensure Sym and PD.

After much experimentation, I came up with:

`a(it,jt) = (vec(it)+vec(jt))/((it-1)^2+(jt-1)^2);` If $it \neq jt$

`a(it,it) = x(it)` if $it=jt$

But this is PD till about 500x500.

1. [XLATMR](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/misc/xlatmr/xlatmr.html). [With all the grading and scaling, its too difficult to understand. Especially since I cannot understand the underlying linear algebra]

Can someone give me a function in x (vector) and i,j (indices) which meets the above requirements?

Comment: Try adding a large number $\alpha$ (on the order of the condition number) to the diagonal entries of your matrix.  This is equivalent to adding $\alpha$ to each of your eigenvalues and should improve the condition number.

Comment: @AronAhmadia, Works brilliantly! Thanks! However, what large number should I add? I tried N itself and it worked till 5000x5000 (just finished simulations), will using `a+N*eye(N,N)` ensure that it will work for all values beyond 5000? Can you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get a dense positive definite matrix with condition number $c$ cheaply, pick a diagonal matrix $D$ whose diagonal consists of numbers from $[1,c]$ (which will be the eigenvalues), with $1$ and $c$ chosen at least once, and a vector $u$. Then apply a similarity transformation, via Householder transformations, to form the matrix $A:=(I-tuu^T)D(I-tuu^T)$, where $t=2/u^Tu$.

To form this matrix with $O(n^2)$ operations, compute $v:=Du$, $s:=t^2u^Tv/2$, $w:=tv-su$ in $O(n)$ operations and then $A$ as $A=D-uw^T-wu^T$. (If you choose $u$ as the all-one vector, the number of multiplications needed is only $O(n)$.)

Note that the behavior of CG depends a lot on the eigenvalue distribution, which you can easily confirm by varying $D$.

(Adding $\alpha$ to an arbitrary symmetric matrix $A$ needs $\alpha$ larger than the largest eigenvalue. This is hard to compute; so one would have to choose $\alpha=\|A\|$, but then the condition number will generally be very small, not a realistic test case for CG.)

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: How should I change the algorithm to provide me matrices when I provide the eigen values? For instance, I want a non-symmetric matrix with eigen values `1,-1,2,-2...50,-50`.

Comment: $D=Diag(-50:50)$ in the above recipe gives you these eigenvalues, but with this choice the matrix is now symmetric indefinite, and CG wouldn't solve such a problem. And in your comment you even ask for a nonsymmetric matrix, wehre CG also doesn't apply. Maybe it is best to pose a new question with what precisely you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a large number $\alpha$ (on the order of the norm of the matrix) to the diagonal entries of your matrix. This is equivalent to adding $\alpha$ to each of your eigenvalues and should improve the condition number by reducing the gap between the largest and smallest eigenvalues.

Comment: For reference see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you would do it with just one vector, but with two random vectors $x$ and $\theta$ of size $N$, you can produce a positive semi-definite matrix via
$$
U=\prod_i R_i(\theta_i)\\
A=U\mbox{diag}(\mbox{abs}(x)) U^\ast
$$
where $R_i(\cdot)$ is a rotation in the plane of the axes $i$ and $i+1 \mbox{ mod } N$.

If you want to improve the condition number, you can add a fixed positive value to $x$ and rescale if need be.

Comment: I'm sorry but my math isn't all that great yet. Does $U^*$ denote transpose? What does rotation in the plane mean? Also, storing 2 vectors will be a little expensive but still, this look likes a very interesting way.

Comment: $R_i(\theta_i)=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots \\ 0 & \ddots \\ &&\cos \theta_i & \sin \theta_i \\ & & -\sin \theta_i & \cos \theta_i\\ & & & &1 \\ && & & & \ddots\end{matrix}\right)$ is the rotation matrix. $U^\ast$ denotes the complex conjugate transposed matrix (assuming all is real, it's just the transpose).

Answer (score 2):

An entirely different way to do it would be like this: consider a random vector $x$, then $A=xx^T$ is a rank-one matrix with $N-1$ eigenvalues equal to zero and one strictly positive eigenvalue equal to $\|x\|^2$ with eigenvector $x$. It's also symmetric.

To construct a dense SPD matrix, add together many such rank-1 matrices. In other words, if you have $M$ vectors $x_i$ (e.g. random vectors), then
$$ A = \sum_{i=1}^M x_i x_i^T $$
is SPD if $M\ge N$ and if the vectors $x_i$ a linearly independent (if they are not linearly independent, then $A$ is positive semidefinite). You can verify if your $M$ vectors (or the first $M\ge N$ vectors you draw from the random process) are linearly independent using Gram-Schmidt successive orthogonalization, but you're also likely to get an SPD matrix if you simply choose $M \gg N$ vectors.